# I installed Pillow but i get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, modulenotfounderror

When I try to use  `from PIL import ImageGrab` it gives me this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

I installed it with `pip install pillow` and checked if it is installed with `pip show pillow`. It says I have **Version: 8.1.2**

I am using **python 3.9** and sublime text 3

In the internet I saw most people with that problem have a not maching python version with the pillow version, but mine should work as far as I understood..? (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

However its not working and I am trying to fix this since about two hours and I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Try `import sys` followed by `print(sys.executable)` to see what you are actually running.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried, i get "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
"

Comment: Ok, and `pip show pillow`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell It just says I have Version: 8.1.2

Comment: Normally it shows the location too...

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is the full message i get with "pip show pillow"

C:\Users\claud>pip show pillow
Name: pillow
Version: 8.1.2
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Alex Clark (PIL Fork Author)
Author-email: aclark@python-pillow.org
License: HPND
Location: c:\users\claud\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

C:\Users\claud>

Answer (score 0):

You might have different versions of python installed and pip is installing pillow for a different version.

A good way to avoid this is using `python -m pip install pillow` instead of `pip install pillow`.

Comment: When I try this, i get :

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\claud\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (8.1.2)

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with `pip3 install pillow`

The fact is that you installed it for python2 but your are using python3 ;)

Comment: That's what i get if i try "pip3 install pillow" :        

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\claud\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (8.1.2)